# what's the difference among no, cno, and ino remap with vimperator?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox, keyboard, vimperator

i currently have the following vimperatorrc setup:
" mswin.vimp - mappings to make copy/paste in Vimperator behave like Windows
" Maintainer: Doug Kearns 
" Last Change: 31 Oct 2008

noremap  
noremap  
" TODO: this should probably be  - see :help dos-CTRL-break in Vim
noremap

inoremap  
inoremap  
inoremap

noremap  
noremap  
noremap  
noremap  
noremap  
noremap

cnoremap  
cnoremap  
cnoremap  
cnoremap  
cnoremap  
cnoremap  
cnoremap

inoremap  
inoremap  
inoremap  
inoremap  
inoremap  
inoremap  
inoremap

however, i have no idea how it works since the vimperator documentation doesn't seem to explain it

Answer (score 5):

Here's the link to the relevant Vimperator documentation page, which explains it pretty well:
http://vimperator.org/help/vimperator/map.xhtml

> Keys can be mapped in four distinct modes:
>
> Normal mode: When browsing normally
>
> Visual mode: When selecting text with the cursor keys
>
> Insert mode: When interacting with text fields on a website
>
> Command-line mode: When typing into the Vimperator command line

In direct answer to your title:

**no** refers to mappings that are used when in normal mode

**cno** refers to mappings that are used when in command-line mode

**ino** refers to mappings that are used when in insert mode